# TortoiseSVN Keeps Crashing Explorer on Windows Vista

Tags: svn, windows-vista, tortoisesvn

Has anyone else experienced this?  I have uninstalled and reinstalled TortoiseSVN as well as followed a suggestion I found online about turning off the icon overlays but Explorer on Windows Vista will still crash when I perform certain operations like pulling up the context menu (i.e. Right Click), hitting the delete key, hitting Ctrl+C and the likes, etc.  Even hitting Windows+E crashes explorer often.

It isn't consistent but this happens for the majority of the time.  I haven't tried to update to v1.6.3 yet (just noticed that it was released); however, has anyone else experienced this issue and figured out a way to resolve it?

Update:
Currently install version is 1.6.2.16344.

Update 2:
Uninstalled 1.6.2.16344, rebooted, Installed 1.6.3.16613 and the issue remains.

Comment: 1st view and someone votes to close it w/o a comment?  I'd like to know why at least.

Comment: Same problem on Windows 7. I'm using the latest (1.7.0) 64-bit version of TortoiseSVN and once installed, after a reboot, it causes Windows Explorer to crash making the computer inoperable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this problem with one release on one of our dev's systems, but upgrading to the latest fixed it.  Try upgrading - it will probably correct your issue.

Comment: After upgrading to the latest version I still experience the issue; however, after the computer has erred a few times, it appears the issue becomes less frequent.  Hopefully it'll eventually just disappear altogether.

Answer (score 2):

From the TortoiseSVN.net page about [known vista issues](http://tortoisesvn.net/vistaproblems):

> Version 1.4.2 has some problems with the explorer. Use version 1.4.3 which has this fixed.

An update might help, in case you're still on <1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I have windows xp and the newest version does this to me. :\

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue too... very frustrating.  Sometimes my PC would perma-hang and sometimes would hang for a few seconds and then come back in VGA mode as if the graphics driver has been uninstalled...  Either way I would have to reboot.

anyway, this is my latest offering that appears to be working for me so far.

In the tortoiseSVN settings/advanced, set showContextMenuIcons to false.

Doesn't look as good, but as I say, so far no problems.

cheers